# If one angle of two triangles and the two medians to the two sides forming this angle are equal are the two triangles congruent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

If one angle of two triangles and the two medians to the two sides forming this angle are equal, will the two triangles be congruent? For example, in triangles $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$, we have angle $A = A'$ and medians $BD = B'D'$ and $CE = C'E'$.

I have tried with Geogebra and indeed they are congruent. I used the fact that the 3 medians intersect at a point that has a distance of $\frac{1}{3}$ of its length from the origin vertex. By keeping one median fixed, I rotated the second one around the intersecting point and indeed there are two points which "see" the side $BC$ by a given angle, both of them resulting to the same triangles.

How do I solve it geometrically?

Let's name the intersection point of the 3 medians $O$. I started by assuming that $BC \neq B'C'$, then since the other two sides of the small triangles (formed by the $\frac{2}{3}$ of the medians) are equal, then angle $BOC \neq B'O'C'$. Then also angles $DOE \neq D'O'E'$, so, segment $DE \neq D'E'$. But I don't know how to go further.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider the Figure above, where I used your notation, and at the beginning I followed a path similar to the one suggested by [Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93935/michael-hoppe) in his answer.

1. Draw segment $BD$ (the first given median) and let $O$ be the centroid of the desired triangle, so that $\overline{BO} = 2\overline{OD}$.
2. Draw the unique (up to reflection with respect to $BD$) circumference $\gamma_1$ passing through $B$ and $D$ and such that the chord $BD$ subtends on it the desidered angle $\angle BAD$.
3. Draw then the circle $\gamma_2$ passing through the midpoint of $BD$, and internally tangent to $\gamma_1$ in $B$. This is the locus of the *midpoints of any chord on $\gamma_1$ having one endpoint in $B$*.
4. Draw $\gamma_3$, the circle centered in $O$ with radius equal to $\frac13\overline{CE}$, where $CE$ is the second given median.
5. $\gamma_3$ has **at most one intersection point** with $\gamma_2$ (in the half-plane where $A$, too, must lie).

Now it suffices to demonstrate that the above mentioned intersection point between $\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_2$ is in fact the uniquely determined point $E$.

In particular, since $BE \cong AE$ by our construction, we need to show that $C = EO \cap AD$ is such that $AD \cong DC$.

Consider triangle $\triangle ABD$ cut by $EC$. By Menelaus's Theorem you have 
$$\frac{\overline{BO}}{\overline{OD}}\cdot \frac{\overline{DC}}{\overline{AC}}\cdot \frac{\overline{AE}}{\overline{BE}} = 1,$$
hence
$$\overline{AC} = 2\overline{DC},$$
and the thesis follows. $\blacksquare$

Comment: dfnu: How do we construct (2)?

Comment: @Samuel you mean the circle $\gamma_1$? Or $\gamma_2$?

Comment: @Samuel, if you are referring to $\gamma_1$, for example you can construct the unique (up to reflection) isosceles triangle $\triangle MBD$, with $\angle MBD \cong \angle MDB = \frac{\pi}2 - \angle BAC$. Then $\gamma_1$ has center $M$, and passes through $B$ and $D$. And of course $\gamma_2$ is the circle through $M$, $B$, and the midpoint of $BD$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sketch to construct the triangle as follows.  Draw $BD$ and determine $O$ such that $BO:OD=2:1$.  Draw the chord over $BD$ such that on that chord $BD$ appears under $\alpha$.  This in one locus for $A$.  Pick a point $A'$ on the circle.  Next step is to double $A'D$ over $D$ to get $C'$.  If the choice of $A'$ meets the condition $C'E=CE$ then $A'=A$.  It seems that the construction gives a unique triangle.